# How can I make my CMD commands as a shortcut?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to automate one of my mostly used cmd command.I want to make a shortcut file or any file when clicked, will do the job. For example: I want to execute a java file, the command will look something like the following:

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin> java.exe  -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -javaagent:BurpSuiteLoader_v2020.7.jar -noverify -jar burpsuite_pro_v2020.7.jar
```

It is to be noted that `BurpSuiteLoader_v2020.7.jar` and `burpsuite_pro_v2020.7.jar` are located in the same file of java.exe ie. in the bin folder. Now how can I automate this task so that when I open batch file( or any other file as a shortcut) this task will be done. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just put that command line into a batch file. What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: I copied the command and pasted it into batch file but doesnt work

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are asking windows to guess where files are instead of telling it.

```
 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin\java.exe"  -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -javaagent:"<MISSING_FILE_PATH>\BurpSuiteLoader_v2020.7.jar" -noverify -jar "<MISSING_FILE_PATH>\burpsuite_pro_v2020.7.jar"
```

Comment: I took the freedom to insert a couple of quotes to make it work with spaces in the path/filenames.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just copied it and put the file folder location and saved it as .bat file. Now it works. :)